# ActiveJDBC @BelongsTo JOIN? Cached?

Tags: activejdbc

Let's say I have a model M1.java that contains
`@BelongsTo(foreignKeyName = "m2_id", parent = M2.class)`
and then after loading M1 I do
`M2 myM2 = myM1.parent(M2.class)`
I suppose an extra query is made to fetch the M2 object (similar to Hibernate FetchType.LAZY), how can we force a JOIN on the first query (that loads M1 object(s))?

In the case it's not possible, or that I don't want to join in certain cases, will every call to `parent(M2.class)` re-run the query to load M2 or will it be cached in the M1 object after the first "fetch"?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I found this page http://javalite.io/lazy_and_eager that explains that the parent won't be cached unless I use the `include()` method.
The problem is when I use it I see in the logs the query to select the parents with one query BUT I still see the extra queries to load them 1 by 1 again! So it's not O(2) instead of O(n+1), but O(n+2)!

```
...
// Both test tables contain 1 row
List<M1> myM1s = M1.where(query, params).include(M2.class);
...
// Duplicating 3 times the print statement for test purpose
System.out.println(myM1s.get(0).parent(M2.class));
System.out.println(myM1s.get(0).parent(M2.class));
System.out.println(myM1s.get(0).parent(M2.class));
...
```

Logs

```
Query: "SELECT * FROM m1 WHERE...", with parameters:...
Query: "SELECT * FROM m2 WHERE id IN (1)"
Query: "SELECT * FROM m2 WHERE id = ?", with parameters: <1>
[print statement]
Query: "SELECT * FROM m2 WHERE id = ?", with parameters: <1>
[print statement]
Query: "SELECT * FROM m2 WHERE id = ?", with parameters: <1>
[print statement]
```

What is going on?

Comment: By the way, if your foreign key name is `m2_id`, then you do not need the annotation

Comment: So no JOIN possible right?

Comment: this is not what I said. Since  name of your foreign key follows ActiveJDBC naming conventions, your annotation is redundant.

Comment: Yeah I know ;-) Just asking because you didn't reply about the JOIN

Comment: this is because in One-to-Many relationship, there is no JOIN:)

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate your experience. Here is the test that is identical to your code: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/test/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/IncludesTest.java#L32

Line 38 checks that the two references point to the same exact object. Also, the test prints this:

```
[main] INFO org.javalite.activejdbc.LazyList - Query: "SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE city = ? ORDER BY id", with parameters: <Springfield>, took: 11 milliseconds
[main] INFO org.javalite.activejdbc.LazyList - Query: "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (?, ?)", with parameters: <1>, <2>, took: 9 milliseconds
```

As you can see, the framework works as expected. You can clone sources and run in your environment to validate this.

Something must be wrong with your environment?

Comment: What do you think could be "wrong" in my environment that would make ActiveJDBC run a query every time I call the .parent() method?

Comment: I do not know. If you could recreate this problem in a small program and then post the issue: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/issues, I could look into it.